# I need to join the two requests in one, how can I do it in angular/rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

This is my code in which I am using forkJoin to make the two requests using operator map.

```html
  private getUserInfo() {
    this.spinner.show();
    let res1 = this.user.getUser()
    let res2 = this.authService.getAccountMe();
    forkJoin([res1, res2]).subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
    this.spinner.hide();
    ....
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: You could also use Promise.all

Comment: Hello Javier Welcome, Can you add a description of your problem to have better understanding about the code

Comment: @CharlieV Sorry, if I didn't explain well, this is my first time on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want an unique object you can use `pipe(map)` in the way

```
forkJoin([res1, res2]).pipe(
    map(([res1, res2]: [any, any]) => ({ ...res1, ...res2 }))
  );
```

or

```
forkJoin([res1, res2]).pipe(
    map(([res1, res2]: [any, any]) => ({ user:res1, account:res2 }))
  );
```

But it's a bit confused your question

Comment: Yes, I know. Sorry, this is my first time on Stackoverflow. But you have the answer.

Comment: actually for the second solution you can do: `forkJoin({user: res1, account: res2 })` without `map`

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are getting the data and not doing anything with it. Instead, the function should return an observable that returns the data, right?

I think what you're looking for is this...

```js
private getUserInfo() {
  this.spinner.show();
  const res1 = this.user.getUser();
  const res2 = this.authService.getAccountMe();
  return forkJoin([res1, res2]).pipe(
    tap(() => this.spinner.hide()),
    shareReplay(1) // not needed if only one thing will be using the returned observable.
  );
}
```